# How can I check if two Span<T> intersect?

Tags: c#

Consider the following function:

```
public static bool TryToDoStuff(ReadOnlySpan<byte> input, Span<byte> destination) {
    ...
}
```

This function returns whether it was able to "do stuff" on `destination` based on `input`'s content.

I'd like to check if the **memory regions "wrapped" by** `input` and `destination` intersect, and if so, throw an exception, since this would corrupt `input`'s data. **How can I do that (without reflection or unsafe code)?**

I know I could write some xmldoc and warn the users that the parameters should not intersect, but that's a poor man's solution.

Edit: for those asking for examples, Wazner's examples are on point.

```
// On arrays
Span<byte> firstArray = new byte[10];
Span<byte> secondArray = new byte[10];
Intersects<byte>(firstArray.Slice(5, 5), firstArray.Slice(3, 5)); // Should throw
Intersects<byte>(firstArray.Slice(5, 5), secondArray.Slice(3, 5)); // Should not throw

// And on stackallocated memory
Span<byte> firstStack = stackalloc byte[10];
Span<byte> secondStack = stackalloc byte[10];
Intersects<byte>(firstStack.Slice(5, 5), firstStack.Slice(3, 5)); // Should throw
Intersects<byte>(firstStack.Slice(5, 5), secondStack.Slice(3, 5)); // Should not throw
```

Comment: `Span<T>` implements method `int32 IndexOfAny(ReadOnlySpan<T> values)`. Have you tried something like `if (destination.IndexOfAny(input) >= 0) throw new IntersectException();`?

Comment: I may have poorly expressed myself; I have now edited the question to make what I meant by 'intersect' clearer. But thanks for the attempt :)

Comment: @MichalŠuvada: That would be comparing values, not memory locations, which is what I believe the OP is interested in.

Comment: Interesting question. `The equality operator checks whether two spans refer to the same chunk of memory, but that's the nearest I could see :(

Comment: @DaisyShipton - so `Slice` the first and last elements from the longer span then work through all elements of the shorter span `Slice`ing them and comparing should work, but not be pretty

Comment: @DaisyShipton - oops, no. Slight brainfart in above. Longer span could completely enclose shorter span, so you have to iterate the longer span with start/end of shorter one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Right. So if the spans can be reasonably long, it's "feasible but not practical" :(

Comment: @Trauer could you post some example data expected to throw Exception?

Comment: Just wind the clock back a bit, before Span.  If the arguments are `byte[]`, would you have added such a comment to the xmldoc?  Maybe that is more obviously wrong to the client programmer, but it should be as obviously wrong when he understands Span.  Theoretically.

Comment: @HansPassant - how do you get two `byte[]`s that are different but referring to the same block of memory without doing something severely unsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an issue on dotnet/corefx repository and one of the contributors posted this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.overlaps?view=netcore-2.1

So yeah, there is a elegant, concise, safe and within-framework solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is one way to do this using the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` NuGet package. It provides low-level methods such as `ByteOffset` and `SizeOf`.

With these methods you are able to write the following method:

```
public static bool Intersects<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> a, ReadOnlySpan<T> b) 
{
    var elementSize = Unsafe.SizeOf<T>();
    var distance = (long)Unsafe.ByteOffset<T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(a), ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(b));
    if (distance < 0) 
    {
        return -distance < b.Length * elementSize;
    }
    else if (distance > 0) 
    {
        return distance < a.Length * elementSize;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method determines the distance between the first element in each span, in bytes. It then determines whether this distance is less than the number of items in the span times the size, in bytes, of a single element in the span.

By using `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>` we allow this method to be used even on non-primitive types. Reference types such as strings and classes are the size of the native integer (`IntPtr.Size`).

Below a few test cases that indicates that this method works:

```
// On arrays
Span<byte> firstArray = new byte[10];
Span<byte> secondArray = new byte[10];
Intersects<byte>(firstArray.Slice(5, 5), firstArray.Slice(3, 5)); // true
Intersects<byte>(firstArray.Slice(5, 5), secondArray.Slice(3, 5)); // false

// And on stackallocated memory
Span<byte> firstStack = stackalloc byte[10];
Span<byte> secondStack = stackalloc byte[10];
Intersects<byte>(firstStack.Slice(5, 5), firstStack.Slice(3, 5)); // true
Intersects<byte>(firstStack.Slice(5, 5), secondStack.Slice(3, 5)); // false
```

*Note: The `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` package requires the use of ref-returns, this is a feature only available starting C# 7*

Comment: This does solve my problem, I believe, since I'm dealing with bytes. But out of curiosity, does Unsafe.SizeOf<T>() behaves correctly with any T?

Comment: @Trauer I can't say for **any** T, but I have tested it with Spans of custom structs, strings, class types and most primitive types. I have modified the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

"without using reflection or unsafe code" - not possible, because the `_pointer` property of `Span<T>` is not publicly exposed in any way:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/ab27e64721496ab7404fd52d8d7720db572fc2f4/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Span.Fast.cs#L30

Comment: As per the comments in the question, it looks like it's *possible* - but not necessarily *practical*.